# Create Websocket Secure on a HTTPS web server in express app

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have a application in express.js. Am unable to create wss on a HTTPS web server.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cfg = {
    ssl: true,
    port: 8001,
    ssl_key: 'sslcert/ssl.key',
    ssl_cert: 'sslcert/ssl.crt'
};
var httpServ = (cfg.ssl) ? require('https') : require('http');
if (cfg.ssl) {
    httpsServer = httpServ.createServer({
            key: fs.readFileSync(cfg.ssl_key),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(cfg.ssl_cert)
        }, app)
        .listen(cfg.port, function () {
            console.log('Magic happening at https://Secure');
        });
} else {
    httpsServer = httpServ.createServer(app)
        .listen(cfg.port, function () {
            console.log('Magic happening at http://InSecure');
        });
}
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket')
    .server;
var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: httpsServer
});

wsServer.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('Socket Connected');
});
```

I'm under the impression that passing a reference of the web server to WebSocket, then WebSocket would know the port and SSL capabilities of the server. But every time I get an error in the console

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8001/?trackme=TUKOCVPAF' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

**How can I create a wss://localhost:8001/?trackme=TUKOCVPAF' when creating the Websocket..??**

Comment: Why does the error state `ws://` and not `wss://`?

Comment: Yes Robert, that's what is the problem. It should create a wss:// but its trying to create a ws:// . Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: How do you create the client socket?

Comment: oh !!, the problem got resolved, the client was trying to create the 'ws://' socket. Thanks a lot.